# Why | matches every string in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am having trouble understanding this code below:

```
var reg=/|/;

reg.test('ssdws');//returns true no matter what the string parameter is.
```

I know the result, but why?

Comment: `|` is special character, if you escape it `/\|/` it will match nothing.

Comment: Yes,| is a special character,but /\|/ will match |.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/|/` means `<empty string>` OR `<empty string>`, effectively means a pattern of `<empty string>`.

Since there are infinitely many empty strings in between 2 characters, before the first character, after the last character, or in an empty string, `/|/.test(input)` will return `true` for any string.

If you want to match the literal character `|`, you need to escape it, i.e. `/\|/`. Then `/\|/.test(input)` will return `true` **if and only if** there is a `|` in the input string.

Comment: As you see,/^|$/ will match nothing but empty string.(it means empty string from start to end).But the result is the same as /|/.

Comment: @JoyceLee: No. `/^|$/` matches the beginning of the string OR the end of the string. A string always has a beginning (and an end), so it will always result in a match.

Answer (score 2):

the `|` means "or" in regex. So you're effectively saying "anything or anything"

Which of course means anything goes.

Comment: I think it means "zero-length string or zero-length string" rather than "anything or anything".

Comment: @spinningarrow: Can you name anything that is not matched by "zero-length string"? :-)

Comment: @spinningarrow good point - I figured the bigger picture was in view here - obviously "zero-length string" puts no real constraints on what that regex will match.

Comment: @Bergi: Well, everything that is not a zero-length string. I think the distinction is in what you mean by 'matched' – `/|/.test('whatever')` will return true not because it matched the word 'whatever' but because it matched the zero-length string preceding 'w'. You can see this if you do `'whatever'.match(/|/)`: the result is `[""]`.